# Change display order of a content type fields in the view tab

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

How can i change the **`order of displaying fields`** details of a node of a content type in D8 ? Its neither specified in the **`Manage form display`** or in the **`Manage display`** of the content type management menu .

**`PS`** : I have added existing fields from another content type to this content type . Will that's display order taken in to this ? How can i change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields are sorted by weight, which is hidden by default, because you can reorder the rows by dragging. You can switch off dragging and input the weights by hand with *Show row weights*.

Doesn't matter if the fields are used in multiple content types, you can arrange them in each content type individually.